# JAX-RX - Blocked by CORS policy: Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, jax-rs, patch

I am using Spring boot with [Jersey 2.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jersey/2.1.0.RELEASE)

and Ionic to develop an App, I've tried every single post I've found but none solved this problem for me the error I am getting, including those which say about creating the `@PATCH` interface annotation yourself.

So, the thing is I am getting this error on the client side when testing on the browser when doing a `PATCH` request:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: Method PATCH is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

The filters I have for the response is the following, I don't understand why I'm getting this if I have `PATCH` as an allowed method and it works perfectly on Postman:

Filter:

```
@Provider
public final class ResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

        headers.putSingle("Accept-Patch", "*");
        headers.putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        headers.putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        headers.putSingle("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        headers.putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    }
}
```

Method which uses `PATCH`:

```
import javax.ws.rs.PATCH;


@PATCH
    @Path("/{username}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response actualizarPassword(@Valid @NotNull(message = "user must not be null") final UserDTO userDTO,
                                      @PathParam("username") final String username,
                                      @QueryParam("codigo") @NotNull(message = "codigo musnt be null") final String codigo) {
        userDTO.setUsername(username);
        this.usersService.actualizarPassword(this.userDTOMapper.map(userDTO), codigo);

        return Response.noContent().build();
    }
```

As I said, I also tried to create an annotation with `PATCH` as I read in some answers but this http method is supposed to be included on Jersey 2.1 and it indeed is as it can be see in the previous piece of code, the interface I created was:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@HttpMethod("PATCH")
public @interface PATCH {
}
```

And if I do a POSTMAN request, these are the headers I get:

```
Accept-Patch →*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Max-Age →3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
Cache-Control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma →no-cache
Expires →0
X-Frame-Options →DENY
Content-Type →application/json
Content-Length →54
Date →Wed, 07 Nov 2018 07:46:45 GMT
```

And incase it's somehow related, this is my SpringSecurity config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web ) throws Exception
    {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers( HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**" );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I've printed the code that the response has and I get a `200`. However, I keep getting this error.

**UPDATE 2**

As requested by sideshowbarker, I made an `OPTIONS` request with POSTMAN and this is the headers:

```
Allow →HEAD,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH
Last-modified →Wed, 07 Nov 2018 10:07:57 GMT+01:00
Accept-Patch →*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Max-Age →3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Content-Type →application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml
Content-Length →1165
Date →Wed, 07 Nov 2018 09:07:57 GMT
```

**UPDATE 3**

I checked the headers in dev tools as suggested by  and the PATCH method isn't there. Why is this? Why is it there if I use POSTMAN but not with my Ionic App?

[image]

Please help, I've been struggling with this for days...

Thanks

Comment: Try testing Postman with an OPTIONS request. Because your browser isn’t actually ever getting around to trying the PATCH request from your frontend code. The browser first does a CORS preflight OPTIONS request, and that fails. So you need to figure out how to configure your Spring backend to respond to the CORS preflight OPTIONS request in the way that the browser needs in order to consider it a success. So you may want to spend some time looking through https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcors%5D+%5Bspring%5D+options or https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcors%5D+%5Bspring-boot%5D+options

Comment: done, I put the response in the 2nd update @sideshowbarker

Comment: The response body for the OPTIONS response isn’t relevant to the question. In fact that OPTIONS response shouldn’t have a response body. You need to examine the HTTP response headers for the OPTIONS response. And you should actually do that in browser devtools, not with Postman. But I guess you could start by checking the headers with Postman.

Comment: I've updated the 'update 2' @sideshowbarker

Comment: You really want to use the Network pane in browser devtools to check the response — both the response headers and the HTTP status code of the response. If the browser were getting the same response as what you show you’re getting from Postman, then the browser wouldn’t be reporting that *“Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response”* message.

Comment: hi @sideshowbarker , indeed PATCH isn't there!! why is this? is there anything to solve it? why is it in postman and not here? I made an update to the post

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Okay I am so idiot that I can't even believe it myself. I was using [this plugin for Chrome] [1](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en)

which was modifying the headers from the response. Noticed it thanks to @sideshowbarker . It's such an idiot thing but that I bet it might happen to other people too.

Thanks alot @sideshowbarker.

Comment: You saved my life ! I forgot a CORS plugin active and my Microsoft graph patch request was being denied, when I turned off the plugin , everything went back to work like a charm

Comment: happened to me as well! THANK YOU :)
I was using the following plugin:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

Comment: You saved my brain man! I was going crazy and totally forgot about that plugin!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I almost had a sleepless night because of this chrome's CORS extension.

Comment: I also fell into this error. Disabled that plugin on the fly and hit the Save button. Works inmediately. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! A customer was having this CORS issue with an embedded component (containing an iframe) of our company's product on the customer's site, and this was the cause of it. Who knows how long that would have taken to figure out without your SO answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue as well. I had a chrome CORS plugin enabled for CORS, and seems it's modifying the header before making a request. Disabling it just worked, such a blunder :)